# How to replace all items in a list with their order in python?

Tags: python, list

Let's take this list :

```
L = [8,1,4,2]
```

I would like to replace its elements with their order.
Expected result :

```
[4,1,3,2]
```

The following script works but is really unefficient with its double for loop :

```
L_result = []
for i in L :
    order = 1
    for j in L :
        if i > j :
            order += 1
    L_result.append(order)
```

Comment: You can create a sorted list from L, then create a dict from that with the list items as keys and orders as values. And then create a new list where each list item from L is replaced by the order by looking up dict. This assumes that there are no items twice in L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) + [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
L = [8, 1, 4, 2]

positions = {e: i for i, e in enumerate(sorted(L), 1)}
result = [positions[e] for e in L]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[4, 1, 3, 2]
```

This approach is `O(n log n)` since is sorting the array. If `L` have duplicates values, you can do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

L = [8, 1, 4, 8, 2]

positions = defaultdict(deque)
for i, e in enumerate(sorted(L), 1):
    positions[e].append(i)

result = [positions[e].popleft() for e in L]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
```

The reason for using a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is to make order stable, the first 8 has the first position, while at the same time keeping the popleft operation `O(1)`, therefore the algorithm remains `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Though if a value is duplicated in `L` this won't work. That being said, OP's code also doesn't work for duplicates